# Right way to handle list of objects in a "polymorphic" way

Tags: kotlin, polymorphism

I am looking for way to handle a list of objects in a "polymorphic" way in the manner that you can for a single object.  Just to recap what *does* work:

```
interface Animal{
   fun sayHello(): String
}
class Dog: Animal{
   override fun sayHello() = "Hello, I'm a dog"
}
class Cat: Animal{
   override fun sayHello() = "Hello, I'm a cat
}

fun printGreeting(animal: Animal){
   println(animal.sayHello())
}
```

Then of course I can do the following:

```
val cat = Cat()
val dog = Dog()
printGreeting(cat) // "Hello, I'm a cat"
printGreeting(dog) // "Hello, I'm a dog"
```

Now imagine I have a `List<Animal>` and want to handle that in a similar way.  I know the following won't work:

```
fun List<Cat>.sayHello() = "Hello, we are a herd of cats"
fun List<Dog>.sayHello() = "Hello, we are a pack of dogs"

fun printGreeting(animals: List<Animal>){
    println(animals.sayHello())
}
```

I understand that, due to JVM type erasure, the compiler won't even allow you to declare the above extension functions, since after the erasure it amounts to a redeclaration of the same function.

I am looking for a design pattern that allows me to get the the desired behavior.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sealed interface + foreach + when (exhaustive)

Comment: A `List<Animal>` could contain a mixture of Cats and Dogs. I don't think there's a way you can restrict your function to enforce a list of exclusively cats or dogs, so there's no way to create a `printGreeting()` function the way you've described it. Maybe if you define some default greeting for when there's a mix of animals. You can create those extension functions by annotating them with different `@JvmName`s.